# How to migrate existing objects when adding url slug identifier to mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, slug

I'm currently using Mongodb ObjectIds in my urls but I would like to use this module instead:
https://github.com/dylang/shortid

But none of the existing data will have these slugs yet. How can I migrate them all? Everywhere I look people are saying you don't need to migrate data in noSQL.

Here's an example schema, I'm adding the 'shortid' field:

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name    : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
    , description: { type: String, trim: true }
    , comments  : [CommentSchema]
    , shortid : { type: String, required: true }
});
```

My intention is to use urls like /items/PPBqWA9 instead of /items/508cbd80c0e1a44277000003

I will have a .pre('save') method that generates the shortid if it doesn't exist already.

Or maybe I can have the default be a function that calls ShortId.generate()?

Two requirements:
1) Never change it
2) Apply to existing objects retro-actively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your choices are either: have your code deal with the fact that the index can be in transition for a potentially extended period of time, or update everything at once and then do a single code change.

The latter seems less messy, but requires that you be able to batch process all of your item documents. In that case you could:

1. Add a unique index to your schema with a default as you suggested. Using `schema.pre` seems unnecessary since `ShortId.generate` is not an asynchronous function call. Something like `shortid: { type: String, default: ShortId.generate(), required: true,  index: {unique: true}}`
2. Write a script to load all existing items, and save them with the new `shortid` property.
3. Adjust the rest of your code to start using `shortid` rather than the `id`.

Comment: thanks, that's what I was wondering and the default value will never change once there is a value in there? Also, any ideas on batch mongoose for node?

Comment: Correct. The default will only set `shortid` when it has no value, so that will be safe to add. For the script: require the model, do a find to get all of the items, for each item call `markModified('shortid')` and `save`.